# malformed list error creating dataframe from list of dict

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a list of dicts.  The dicts are originally parsed from json.  I'm getting the malformed list error below.  The list looks fine to me.  The list is below the error.  Does anyone see what the issue might be and can you suggest how to fix?

code:

```
import ast

address_list=result_dataframe['address'].tolist()



address_df=pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in address_list])
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-da573ced8322> in <module>
      9 # address_list[:3]
     10 
---> 11 address_df=pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in address_list])

<ipython-input-58-da573ced8322> in <listcomp>(.0)
      9 # address_list[:3]
     10 
---> 11 address_df=pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in address_list])

~/anaconda3/envs/web_scrape_etl/lib/python3.7/ast.py in literal_eval(node_or_string)
     89                     return left - right
     90         return _convert_signed_num(node)
---> 91     return _convert(node_or_string)
     92 
     93 

~/anaconda3/envs/web_scrape_etl/lib/python3.7/ast.py in _convert(node)
     88                 else:
     89                     return left - right
---> 90         return _convert_signed_num(node)
     91     return _convert(node_or_string)
     92 

~/anaconda3/envs/web_scrape_etl/lib/python3.7/ast.py in _convert_signed_num(node)
     61             else:
     62                 return - operand
---> 63         return _convert_num(node)
     64     def _convert(node):
     65         if isinstance(node, Constant):

~/anaconda3/envs/web_scrape_etl/lib/python3.7/ast.py in _convert_num(node)
     53         elif isinstance(node, Num):
     54             return node.n
---> 55         raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
     56     def _convert_signed_num(node):
     57         if isinstance(node, UnaryOp) and isinstance(node.op, (UAdd, USub)):

ValueError: malformed node or string: {'city': 'Cazadero', 'line': '27951 King Ridge Rd', 'postal_code': '95421', 'state_code': 'CA', 'state': 'California', 'county': 'Sonoma', 'fips_code': '06097', 'county_needed_for_uniq': False, 'lat': 38.600149, 'lon': -123.190777}
```

data:

```
address_list=[{'city': 'Cazadero',
  'line': '27951 King Ridge Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Sonoma',
  'fips_code': '06097',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'lat': 38.600149,
  'lon': -123.190777},
 {'city': 'Cazadero',
  'line': '1460 Big Barn Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Sonoma',
  'fips_code': '06097',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'lat': 38.563553,
  'lon': -123.159865},
 {'city': 'Cazadero',
  'line': '23480 Fort Ross Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Sonoma',
  'fips_code': '06097',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'lat': 38.538229,
  'lon': -123.163885},
 {'city': 'Cazadero',
  'line': '85 Sunrise Mountain Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Sonoma',
  'fips_code': '06097',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'lat': 38.504359,
  'lon': -123.075754},
 {'city': 'Cazadero',
  'line': '23800 Fort Ross Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Sonoma',
  'fips_code': '06097',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'lat': 38.534801,
  'lon': -123.168689},
 {'city': 'Guerneville',
  'line': '19800 Old Cazadero Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Sonoma',
  'fips_code': '06097',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'lat': 38.535157,
  'lon': -123.056528},
 {'city': 'Cazadero',
  'line': '2945 Austin Creek Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Sonoma',
  'fips_code': '06097',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'lat': 38.499242,
  'lon': -123.067987},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '38851 S Highway 1',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.773426,
  'lon': -123.533202},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '37891 Old Coast Hwy',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.780578,
  'lon': -123.546428},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': 'Tbd By Co of Mendocino',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'is_approximate': True,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.801474,
  'lon': -123.425175},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '46620 Iversen Ln',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.85319,
  'lon': -123.642963},
 {'city': 'Anchor Bay',
  'line': '45741 Sunset Dr',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.816458,
  'lon': -123.582281},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '38957 Cypress Way',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.77155,
  'lon': -123.531202},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '39051 Cypress Way',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'is_approximate': True,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.801474,
  'lon': -123.425175},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '38954 Cypress Way',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.770058,
  'lon': -123.530914},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '38917 Cypress Way',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.770361,
  'lon': -123.530834},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '39001 Cypress Way',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.770559,
  'lon': -123.53066},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '37900 Marine View Dr',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.780056,
  'lon': -123.543766},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': 'S Highway 1',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'is_approximate': True,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.801474,
  'lon': -123.425175},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '38300 Ocean Ridge Dr',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.794639,
  'lon': -123.529917},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': 'Old Stage',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'is_approximate': True,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.801474,
  'lon': -123.425175},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '35110 Meadow Ct',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'is_approximate': True,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.801474,
  'lon': -123.425175},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': 'Old Stage',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'is_approximate': True,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.801474,
  'lon': -123.425175},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '30101 S Highway 1',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.847588,
  'lon': -123.643029},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '46561 Getchell Gulch Rd',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.808628,
  'lon': -123.568694},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '38060 Ocean Ridge Dr',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.797034,
  'lon': -123.534572},
 {'city': 'Gualala',
  'line': '46601 Gypsy Flat Rd',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.822692,
  'lon': -123.597325},
 {'city': 'Anchor Bay',
  'line': '45971 Sunset Dr',
  'postal_code': '95445',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.820473,
  'lon': -123.56952}]
```

Comment: `result_dataframe['address'].tolist()`. How to recreate `result_dataframe`?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple answer

Think the problem is possibly over-complicating things by trying to use AST.

A list of dicts (which is what you have in `address_list`) is one of the things that can be used directly to build a data frame. This works:

```py
address_list=[{'city': 'Cazadero',
  'line': '27951 King Ridge Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Sonoma',
  'fips_code': '06097',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'lat': 38.600149,
  'lon': -123.190777},
 {'city': 'Cazadero',
  'line': '1460 Big Barn Rd',
  'postal_code': '95421',
# ...etc etc, I removed some...
  'state_code': 'CA',
  'state': 'California',
  'county': 'Mendocino',
  'fips_code': '06045',
  'county_needed_for_uniq': False,
  'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'lat': 38.820473,
  'lon': -123.56952}]

df = pd.DataFrame(address_list)
```

Then you have a working DataFrame with all of the data:

```py
# Print first few lines of the DataFrame...
print(df.head())

       city                    line postal_code state_code       state  \
0  Cazadero     27951 King Ridge Rd       95421         CA  California   
1  Cazadero        1460 Big Barn Rd       95421         CA  California   
2  Cazadero      23480 Fort Ross Rd       95421         CA  California   
3  Cazadero  85 Sunrise Mountain Rd       95421         CA  California   
4  Cazadero      23800 Fort Ross Rd       95421         CA  California   

   county fips_code  county_needed_for_uniq        lat         lon time_zone  \
0  Sonoma     06097                   False  38.600149 -123.190777       NaN   
1  Sonoma     06097                   False  38.563553 -123.159865       NaN   
2  Sonoma     06097                   False  38.538229 -123.163885       NaN   
3  Sonoma     06097                   False  38.504359 -123.075754       NaN   
4  Sonoma     06097                   False  38.534801 -123.168689       NaN   

  is_approximate  
0            NaN  
1            NaN  
2            NaN  
3            NaN  
4            NaN
```

---

### Using AST

Don't think there's any need/reason to use AST, but incidentally: the reason the code you have is not working is because `ast.literal_eval(x)` wants `x` to be a `str` object, but here `x` is a `dict` object.

For completeness, if you change each `dict` (x) back into a `str` by calling `str(x)`, right before feeding it to `ast.literal_eval` (which then does *the exact opposite conversion*, from a `str` back to a `dict`) then that approach works too, though I can't think of any reason to do it this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(str(x)) for x in address_list])
```

So, I think the jist of the **malformed node or string** error is that the 'string' it's expecting is actually a dictionary. Using AST might make sense if you had some dicts stored in text files or something, though even then a parser (JSON parser or similar) would probably be a better option.